# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()'

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and I get a little bit confused on the java program. In my program, I have created 4 time picker which used to pick up time in and time out. After that, an editText will display the total hours.

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date dateb=null;
            Date datec=null;
            Date dateb1=null;
            Date datec1=null;
            Date dateb2=null;
            Date datec2=null;
            Date dateb3=null;
            Date datec3=null;


            try {
                    dateb = format.parse(b);
                    datec = format.parse(c);
                    long difference = datec.getTime() - dateb.getTime();
                    int minutes = (int) ((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                    int hours = (int) ((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24) - 1;
                    editTextH1.setText((hours + ":" + minutes));
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.err.println("ouch!");
                }
                    try {

                         dateb1 = format.parse(d);
                         datec1 = format.parse(e1);
                        long difference1 = datec1.getTime() - dateb1.getTime();
                        int minutes1 = (int) ((difference1 / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                        int hours1 = (int) ((difference1 / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24) - 1;
                        editTextH2.setText((hours1 + ":" + minutes1));
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.err.println("ouch!");
                    }
            try {

                dateb2 = format.parse(f);
                 datec2 = format.parse(g);
                long difference2 = datec2.getTime() - dateb2.getTime();
                int minutes2 = (int) ((difference2 / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                int hours2 = (int) ((difference2 / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24) - 1;
                editTextH3.setText((hours2 + ":" + minutes2));
            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.err.println("ouch!");
            }
            try {
                 dateb3 = format.parse(h);
                 datec3 = format.parse(i);
                long difference3 = datec3.getTime() - dateb3.getTime();
                int minutes3 = (int) ((difference3 / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                int hours3 = (int) ((difference3 / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24) - 1;
                editTextH4.setText((hours3 + ":" + minutes3));
            }catch (Exception e) {

                System.err.println("ouch!");
            }

// display total hours 
                long dateb_sum = dateb.getTime() + dateb1.getTime() + dateb2.getTime()+dateb3.getTime();
                long datec_sum = datec.getTime() + datec1.getTime() + datec2.getTime()+datec3.getTime();
                long difference4 = datec_sum - dateb_sum;
                int minutes4 = (int) ((difference4/ (1000*60)) % 60);
                int hours4  = (int) ((difference4/ (1000*60*60)) % 24)-1;
                editText8.setText((hours4+":"+minutes4));

                }


            }
```

When I run my app, it crashed on the time picker and the project forced to stop.I have initialized all my editText but still getting this error. Anyone can help me? Thanks

**LogCat**

```
 10-01 01:21:13.041    4552-4552/com.example.project.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 4552
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.project.project.WorkDetailsTable$TimePick.onTimeSet(WorkDetailsTable.java:381)
            at android.app.TimePickerDialog.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:145)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I'm pretty sure the error come from the coding below because it doesn't crashed when I remove them. But I need them to calculate the overall total hours!!

```
long dateb_sum = dateb.getTime() + dateb1.getTime() + dateb2.getTime()+dateb3.getTime();
                    long datec_sum = datec.getTime() + datec1.getTime() + datec2.getTime()+datec3.getTime();
                    long difference4 = datec_sum - dateb_sum;
                    int minutes4 = (int) ((difference4/ (1000*60)) % 60);
                    int hours4  = (int) ((difference4/ (1000*60*60)) % 24)-1;
                    editText8.setText((hours4+":"+minutes4));
```

Comment: is this should be datec1 = format.parse(e1); or datec1 = format.parse(e);

Comment: I use e1 instead of e

Comment: certainly looks like one of your Date objects is null when you try to call getTime() on it. Can't see which one it would be, though. Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: @NickJ Do you mean logcat?

Comment: The error message you are getting must be occurring on the section of code near the end, without a try-catch block, but the only way that could happen is if one of your dates was not initialised, which would happen if another exception were swallowed up by your try-catch blocks. Do you have any 'ouch!' messages in the error log?

Comment: @Hoo what is line number `WorkDetailsTable.java:381`?

Comment: and try to print the error message as.. `Log.e("Exception "," "+e.getMessage());` may be you are unable to see the message in log cat but it exists..

Comment: @sourabhbans someone has helped me solved the problem...I can't post answer here since someone has marked my question as duplicated...Refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878412/get-overall-hours-from-two-time-picker

Comment: @Hoo ok... enjoy the codding.. :)

Comment: @sourabhbans kindly refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880980/how-to-save-different-data-from-different-class-to-different-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides crash, I think you are using lot of repeated code, You can clean it up. Use the below method. Pass EditText and dates in params and call as much as you want.

```
setMyTime(EditText editText,String date1, String date2){
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
   try {
             Date d1 = format.parse(date1);
             Date d2 = format.parse(date2);
            long difference = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
            int minutes = (int) ((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
            int hours = (int) ((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24) - 1;
            editText.setText((hours + ":" + minutes));
        }catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println(e.printStackTrace());
        }
}
```

Example:

```
setMyTime(editTextH1,b,c);
setMyTime(editTextH2,d,e);
setMyTime(editTextH3,f,g);
setMyTime(editTextH4,h,i);
```

Comment: When you get an exception, it is unacceptable to just print an idiotic message like `"ouch!"`. Print the message that comes with the exception, *and* the exception class.

Comment: @EJP It would be nice if you can help me to figure out the problem...Thanks

Comment: Try this code and spot the issues easily..

Comment: @Hoo The problem is a common or garden NPE. The solution is not to deference null pointers, as the duplicate says, along with a thousand or more other questions here.

Comment: the problem has solved :)